# How to put a fraction into italics? (No math-mode preferred)

Tags: math-mode

I know, it sounds strange, but I need to have a fraction in italics. I have plenty of tables in my document where in one column everything is always in italics. And there I have one specific table with some simple fractions. I don't need and don't want them in math-mode. I tried following to have it look as text-mode:

```
\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

$\frac{\text{1}}{\text{2}}$ & một \textbf{phần} hai \\ 
\\
$\frac{\text{3}}{\text{4}}$ & ba \textbf{phần} tư \\
\\
$\frac{\text{6}}{\text{8}}$ & sáu \textbf{phần} tám \\

\end{longtable}
```

But when it finally looks as all other text, I can't make it italic. I tried this:

```
\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

$\frac{\text{\textit{1}}}{\text{\textit{2}}}$ & một \textbf{phần} hai \\ 
\\
$\frac{\text{\textit{3}}}{\text{\textit{4}}}$ & ba \textbf{phần} tư \\
\\
$\frac{\text{\textit{6}}}{\text{\textit{8}}}$ & sáu \textbf{phần} tám \\

\end{longtable}
```

but it doesn't look good... I mean: It is not the whole fraction that is in italics - it's only the numbers that went into italics.

[image: italic numbers in fractions]

Does anyone have an idea if there's a better way to have it done?

Comment: "Looking good" is subjective and depends also on the font (in your picture it's a sans-serif one). But instead of your `\text{\textit{1}}` construction you could use simply `\mathit`. Or even define `\newcommand*{\itfrac}[2]{\frac{\mathit{#1}}{\mathit{#2}}}`.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the title "No math-mode preferred".

Comment: You could try something like `$\frac{\it 1}{\it 2}$` or even `${\it \frac{1}{2}}$`. It's definitely shorter.

Comment: What I mean saying "not looking good" is: It is not the whole fraction that is in italics - it's only the numbers that went into italics.

Comment: @RHertel But `\it` shouldn't really be used: [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516)

Comment: @Dominik, you said: *It is not the whole fraction that is in italics - it's only the numbers that went into italics.* So I think that you want also the bar slanted.

Comment: @TorbjørnT Thank you for your comment. I didn't even know `\it` was an "obsolete command". I've been using LaTeX for many years. It's hard to change habits, but I'm glad to learn about new developments.

Comment: @Sigur In some way: yes. If the whole fraction was slanted, everything would be aligned to an invisible slanted line on the left. But as for now every part of the fraction is aligned vertically. Do you get what I mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Simple text fraction

A simple way for simple fractions is the text form `a/b`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[r]{>{\itshape}p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}
  1/2 & một \textbf{phần} hai \\
  3/4 & ba \textbf{phần} tư \\
  6/8 & sáu \textbf{phần} tám \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Package `nicefrac`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[r]{>{\itshape}p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}
  \nicefrac{1}{2} & một \textbf{phần} hai \\
  \nicefrac{3}{4} & ba \textbf{phần} tư \\
  \nicefrac{6}{8} & sáu \textbf{phần} tám \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result nicefrac]

## Package `xfrac`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[r]{>{\itshape}p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}
  \sfrac{1}{2} & một \textbf{phần} hai \\
  \sfrac{3}{4} & ba \textbf{phần} tư \\
  \sfrac{6}{8} & sáu \textbf{phần} tám \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Horizontal fraction line with shifted numerator

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{amstext}
\newcommand*{\itfrac}[2]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \frac{\,\text{\itshape #1}}{\mkern-\thinmuskip\text{\itshape #2}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[r]{>{\itshape}p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}
  \itfrac{1}{2} & một \textbf{phần} hai \\
  \itfrac{3}{4} & ba \textbf{phần} tư \\
  \itfrac{6}{8} & sáu \textbf{phần} tám \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with horizontal fraction line and shifted numerator]

If math fonts should be used, then `\text{\itshape ...}` can be replaced by `\mathit`.

Comment: OK, that's true. But it avoids the typical writing of one digit above the other...

Comment: @Dominik The slash is also a typical form for a fraction especially for text. I have now added a variant with horizontal line, but shifted numerator. The variants with `nicefrac` and `xfrac` act as "nice" compromise between the two extremes.